# Scala pattern matching syntax

Tags: scala, syntax, pattern-matching

I've been playing with scala pattern matching recently and was wondering whether there is a way to create an extractor inside of the case statement. The following code works, but you have to define the extractor first and assign it to a val:

```
val Extr = "(.*)".r
"test" match {
  case Extr(str) => println(str)
}
```

What I would like to do, or what I would like someone to confirm is impossible, is something like this:

```
"test" match {
  case ("(.*)".r)(str) => println(str)
}
```

EDIT: In case anyone from the scala team is reading this: Would it be feasible to implement this?

Comment: +1 for the suggestion! This would be useful indeed in other cases.

Comment: @JPP: Indeed. The case I was originally thinking of was that of `or` and `and` as library functions to build complex extractors from simpler ones.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411573/can-extractors-be-customized-with-parameters-in-the-body-of-a-case-statement-or

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible and I see no way to simplify your first example.

The case statement has to be followed by a *Pattern*. The [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) shows the BNF of patterns in section 8.1. The grammar of patterns is quite powerful, but is really just a pattern, no method calls or constructors are allowed there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and i solved it like this:

```
case x if x.matches("regex") => foo(x)
```

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but it works