# Matching with custom combinations/operators

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I know that you can do matching on lists in a way like

```
val list = List(1,2,3)
list match {
  case head::tail => head
  case _ => //whatever
}
```

so I started to wonder how this works. If I understand correctly, `::` is just an operator, so what's to stop me from doing something like

```
4 match {
  case x + 2 => x //I would expect x=2 here
}
```

If there is a way to create this kind of functionality, how is it done; if not, then why?

Comment: Why don't you use `y-2` (when y = 4)?

Comment: This is more of a curiosity, so I don't have any specific examples, but I imagined this being nice for more complex classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pattern matching takes the input and decomposes it with an `unapply` function.  So in your case, `unapply(4)` would have to return the two numbers that sum to 4.  However, there are many pairs that sum to 4, so the function wouldn't know what to do.

What you need is for the `2` to be accessible to the `unapply` function somehow. A special case class that stores the `2` would work for this:

```
case class Sum(addto: Int) {
    def unapply(i: Int) = Some(i - addto)
}

val Sum2 = Sum(2)
val Sum2(x) = 5  // x = 3
```

(It would be nice to be able to do something like `val Sum(2)(y) = 5` for compactness, but Scala doesn't allow parameterized extractors; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411573/can-extractors-be-customized-with-parameters-in-the-body-of-a-case-statement-or).)

[EDIT: This is a little silly, but you could actually do the following too:

```
val `2 +` = Sum(2)
val `2 +`(y) = 5  // y = 3
```

]

EDIT: The reason the `head::tail` thing works is that there is exactly one way to split the head from the tail of a list.

There's nothing inherently special about `::` versus `+`: you could use `+` if you had a predetermined idea of how you wanted it to break a number.  For example, if you wanted `+` to mean "split in half", then you could do something like:

```
object + {
    def unapply(i: Int) = Some(i-i/2, i/2)
}
```

and use it like:

```
scala> val a + b = 4
a: Int = 2
b: Int = 2

scala> val c + d = 5
c: Int = 3
d: Int = 2
```

EDIT: Finally, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059145/how-is-this-case-class-match-pattern-working) explains that, when pattern matching, `A op B` means the same thing as `op(A,B)`, which makes the syntax look nice.

Comment: I think your edit clears things up for me, I will have to toy around with this concept later tonight

Comment: @Dylan: I rewrote the prose so hopefully it will be less confusing now.

Answer (score 4):

Matching with `case head :: tail` uses an *infix operation pattern* of the form `p1 op p2` which gets translated to `op(p1, p2)` before doing the actual matching. (See [API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.%24colon%24colon) for `::`)

The problem with `+` is the following:

While it is easy to add an

```
object + { 
  def unapply(value: Int): Option[(Int, Int)] = // ...
}
```

object which would do the matching, you may only supply one result per value. E.g.

```
object + { 
  def unapply(value: Int): Option[(Int, Int)] = value match {
    case 0 => Some(0, 0)
    case 4 => Some(3, 1)
    case _ => None
}
```

Now this works:

```
0 match { case x + 0 => x } // returns 0
```

also this

```
4 match { case x + 1 => x } // returns 3
```

But this won’t and you cannot change it:

```
4 match { case x + 2 => x } // does not match
```

No problem for `::`, though, because it is always defined what is `head` and what is `tail` of a list.

Comment: +1 for the API link- I didn't realize that. So from what I gather from that, a List[_] is actually a subclass of :: and therefore a case class and that's why you can match like that? So if I wanted to offer some kind of matching like `"hello" match { case head::tail //h + ello ...` then I would need to make an implicit conversion from a String to my own specialized case class?

Answer (score 1):

There are two `::`s (pronounced "cons") in Scala. One is the operator on `List`s and the other is a class, which represents a non empty list characterized by a head and a tail. So `head` :: `tail` is a constructor pattern, which has nothing to do with the operator.