# Modeling with Scala case class

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class, extractor

I'm attempting to model responses from REST APIs as case classes which I can use pattern matching on.

I thought it would be a good fit assuming inheritance, but I see that this is deprecated.
I know there are already questions related to case classes and inheritance, but my question is more about how you would model the following the "right way" here *without* inheritance.

I started with the following two case classes, which work fine:

```
case class Body(contentType: String, content: String)
case class Response(statusCode: Int, body: Body)
```

i.e. a REST call would return with something like:

```
Response(200, Body("application/json", """{ "foo": "bar" }"""))
```

which I could pattern match like:

```
response match {
  case Response(200, Body("application/json", json)) => println(json)
  case Response(200, Body("text/xml", xml)) => println(xml)
  case Response(_,_) => println("Something unexpected")
}
```

etc. which works fine.

Where I ran into trouble is: I'd like helper extensions for these case classes, such as:

```
case class OK(body: Body) extends Response(200, body)
case class NotFound() extends Response(404, Body("text/plain", "Not Found"))

case class JSON(json: String) extends Body("application/json", json)
case class XML(xml: String) extends Body("text/xml", xml)
```

so that I can do simplified pattern matches like this:

```
response match {
  case OK(JSON(json)) => println(json)
  case OK(XML(xml)) => println(xml)
  case NotFound() => println("Something is not there")

  // And still drop down to this if necessary:
  case Response(302, _) => println("It moved")
}
```

and also which would also allow my REST code to directly use and return:

```
Response(code, Body(contentType, content))
```

which is easier to build a response dynamically.

so...

I can get it to compile (with deprecation warnings) via:

```
case class OK(override val body: Body) extends Response(200, body)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work with pattern matching.

```
Response(200, Body("application/json", "")) match {
  case OK(_) => ":-)"
  case _ => ":-("
}
res0: java.lang.String = :-(
```

Any ideas on how this could work?  I'm open to different approaches, but this was my attempt to find a practical use for case classes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several reasons why case classes [shouldn't be subclassed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653424/what-are-the-disadvantages-to-declaring-scala-case-classes). In your case, the problem becomes that `OK` is another type than (a subtype of) `Response`, therefore the match fails (even if the arguments match, the type doesn't match).

You will want [custom extractors](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112), instead. For example:

```
case class Response(code: Int, body: String)
object OK {
  def apply(body: String) = Response(200, body)
  def unapply(m: Response): Option[String] = m match {
    case Response(200, body) => Some(body)
    case _                   => None
  }
}

def test(m: Response): String = m match {
   case OK(_) => ":-)"
   case _     => ":-("
}

test(Response(300, "Hallo"))  // :-(
test(Response(200, "Welt"))   // :-)
test(OK("Welt"))              // :-)
```

There are few more examples of custom extractors in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738577/matching-with-custom-combinations-operators?lq=1).

Comment: Ah, thank you - I see I've totally missed the purpose of unapply until this; this is very helpful.  Will test this out fully out with my code to make sure I have covered and will accept later tonight.

Comment: Good answer @Sciss. Custom extractors are one of the things I like a lot about Scala.

Comment: @7zark7 Note that when you use custom extractors you lose exhaustiveness guarantees of sealed classes.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral yes I'm seeing that - I'd prefer to use strictly case classes here, but this doesn't seam feasible with the usage requirements I outlined above.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the scala library unfiltered?
http://unfiltered.lessis.me/
It may help you with approaching you problem .
HTH

Comment: I had a look but I quit because there were too many slides, with 1 sentence/a-few-words on each. Is there perhaps any single page version that clarifies what Unfiltered is all about?

Answer (score 1):

While custom extractors mentioned by 0__ can certainly be used, you'll lose exhaustiveness guarantees of sealed type hierarchies. While in the example you gave in the question there's nothing `sealed`, the problem is well suited to them.

In that case, my suggestion is to simply make sure the `case class` is always at the bottom of the type hierarchy, and make the upper classes normal. For example:

```
sealed class Response(val statusCode: Int, val body: Body) sealed
case class Ok(override val body: Body) extends Response(200, body)
sealed class NotOk(statusCode: Int, body: Body) extends Response(statusCode, body)
case object NotFound extends NotOk(404, "Not found")
// and so on...
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, while my first impression was this would not work if I also wanted to allow matches on Response - I see this may work if I define unapply on a Response object as Sciss mentions, and have the "helpers" be the case classes.  Will try both approaches out today and see what fits/works best here.

Comment: Did you mean to write `sealed class Response`?

Comment: @Sciss Yes, and `NotOk` as well. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.