# Dynamic Extractors in Scala

Tags: scala

One of the things I don't like about extractors is that they cannot have parameters. So I cannot have extractors like `Param` in:

```
req match { case Param("foo")(foo) => … }
```

### Dynamic Extractors?

That's unfortunate, and I hope it will change some day, but then this morning I figured I could fix it by using the Dynamic trait.

```
object Params extends Dynamic {
  def selectDynamic(name: String) = new {
    def unapply(params: Map[String, String]): Option[String] = params.get(name)
  }
}
```

… hoping that would allow me use Params in a pattern matching statement like this:

```
req match { case Params.Foo(value) => 
  // matching Map("Foo" -> "Bar"), extracting "Bar" in value
```

### It doesn't work

… but it doesn't work. It seems the compiler is still getting confused.

```
scala> Map("Foo" -> "bar") match { case Params.Foo(value) => value }
<console>:10: error: value applyDynamic is not a member of object Params
error after rewriting to Params.<applyDynamic: error>("Foo")
possible cause: maybe a wrong Dynamic method signature?
              Map("Foo" -> "bar") match { case Params.Foo(value) => value }
                                               ^
<console>:10: error: not found: value value
              Map("Foo" -> "bar") match { case Params.Foo(value) => value }
                                                                    ^
```

Which I find surprising, since

```
object Params {
  object Foo {
    def unapply{params: Map[String, String]): Option[String] = … 
  }
}
```

would work fine. Also, if I assign `Params.Foo` to a variable first, everything is okay:

```
scala> val Foo = Params.Foo
Foo: AnyRef{def unapply(params: Map[String,String]): Option[String]} = Params$$anon$1@f2106d8

scala> Map("Foo" -> "bar") match { case Foo(value) => value }
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
res2: String = bar
```

Should this be considered a bug?

Comment: When I try to compile `Map("" -> "") match { case Params.Foo(value) => 5 }` with your `object Params extends Dynamic` the compiler melts down with a `NullPointerException` - definitely looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner as you can tell from the output of my Scala REPL, it's not the `NullpointerException` that is in my way.

Comment: I would not try to fight the language syntax here and would simply assign the extractor to a constant and use that constant in the `match` block; resorting to Dynamic here looks like a bad idea and in my opinion leads to unreadable non-Scalaesque code which `Dynamic` was not meant for.

Comment: @ErikAllik I'm using extractors like `Params.Foo` as nested objects all the time. I don't see how that is 'unreadable', and 'non-Scalaesque'. Unfiltered uses it all the time, also for [extracting parameters](http://unfiltered.databinder.net/Within+the+Parameters.html), so I don't see why you shouldn't try to make the syntax a little less verbose and clunky. Also the [ScalaDocs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Dynamic) don't mention anything on what `Dynamic` was meant for, other than a pretty generic description that perfectly matches my use case.

Comment: IMO, it makes it look as if `Foo` was an actual static attribute of `Params`, which it's not; it's just a workaround way of passing dynamic string values to a function. In other words, it's unreadable/un-scalaesque for the same reason Scala is a statically typed language with a highly expressive type system and not a dynamically typed language such as Groovy, Python or PHP. But in the end, it's a matter of opinion of course.

Comment: Agreed. The ultimate solution is parameterised extractors, which - according to [this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5435) should be in Scala 2.11, but I haven't found any reference to it yet in the release notes.

Comment: On another note, I think if-else is still a usable tool and pattern matching in Scala has grown to be a little bit overused :)

Comment: `if` that is sensible `then` I would use it `else` I would use pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical answer is [Can extractors be customized with parameters in the body of a case statement (or anywhere else that an extractor would be used)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2411573/1296806)

but [the hacking blog](http://hacking-scala.org/post/49051516694/introduction-to-type-dynamic) suggests the trick of passing arguments as arbitrary names to dynamic selection, as tried in the question.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_60).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> class X(pattern: String) { val RegExp = new { def unapplySeq(s: String) = pattern.r.unapplySeq(s) } }
defined class X

scala> import language._
import language._

scala> case object p extends Dynamic { def selectDynamic(pattern: String) = new X(pattern) }
defined object p

scala> "abcdef" match { case p.`.*(b.*d).*`.RegExp(s) => s }
res0: String = bcd
```

The extra selection is required because of [a crashing bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9712) in 2.11 which is different from the 2.10 error shown in the question:

```
scala> class RegExp(pattern: String) { def unapplySeq(s: String) = pattern.r.unapplySeq(s) }
defined class RegExp

scala> case object p extends Dynamic { def selectDynamic(pattern: String) = new RegExp(pattern) }
defined object p

scala> "abcdef" match { case p.`.*(b.*d).*`(s) => s }
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.PatternTypers$PatternTyper$class.inPlaceAdHocOverloadingResolution(PatternTypers.scala:68)
```

The working example in 2.10:

```
$ scala210 -language:_
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_95).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class X(key: String) { val get = new { def unapply(params: Map[String, String]): Option[String] = params.get(key) }}
object Params extends Dynamic {
  def selectDynamic(name: String) = new X(name)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class X
defined module Params

scala> Map("Foo" -> "bar") match { case Params.Foo.get(value) => value }
res0: String = bar
```

This is similar to what is shown at the end of the question, but makes it obvious that dynamic selection can be used this way.